# Poltergeist 1.9.0 w/Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: poltergeist

The doc says that Poltergeist 1.9.0 should work with Ruby 1.9.3 or higher, but I'm getting an install error when I try to install Poltergeist 1.9.0 on Ubuntu with Ruby 1.9.3.  Is there a workaround other than upgrading Ruby?

PS. I'm also using Cucumber 1.3.19 and Capybara 2.4.4.

```
# gem --version
1.8.23
# ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
# gem install poltergeist
ERROR:  Error installing poltergeist:
    mime-types-data requires Ruby version >= 2.0.
# gem install poltergeist 1.9.0
Fetching: poltergeist-1.9.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: mini_portile2-2.0.0.rc2.gem (100%)
Fetching: mime-types-data-3.2016.0221.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing poltergeist:
    mime-types-data requires Ruby version >= 2.0.
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '1.9.0' (>= 0) in any repository
```

Answer (score 0):

Add mime-types to your Gemfile with a < 3.0 version restriction